# Windows search finds files that don't belong to me

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, windows-search

My Windows 10 machine has several local user accounts. Each user has a home directory on a second drive -- each user's Documents library points there.

When I log in as User A and use the Windows search box, I see files belonging to *all* users, in *all* users' Documents libraries -- not just User A's files.

When I check on the permissions of the user directories, they appear to only be accessible to their owners, but any user can open any other user's files.

How do I set the permissions so that:

1. Each user is denied access to other users' Documents directories.
2. Search only shows results to which the user has access

Answers to Comments:

- I am not logged in as an admin
- The machine is not connected to a domain
- I created the new user directories (I:\users\UserA), set the sharing permissions so that only the designated user has access (I think) and updated each user's account so that their Documents library pointed to the appropriate directory.
  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some examples?  Is this machine connected to a domain?  Windows Search most definitely should not be searching for files in other user's profile directory.

Comment: Did you move the entire user directories to a separate drive or just the location of *Documents* folder in Properties > Location?  Or something else?

Comment: If you are the administrator, you can click on other users' folders and see the files. Windows will tell you that you do not have permission, but you can "continue" (button to press) and see the files.  Non-admin users cannot do this. Make sure the other users are not administrators.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around more in the directory properties, I discovered that while *sharing* was set correctly, *access permissions* under Properties->Security were not. After stripping away read permissions for all but User A, User A's files stopped showing up in User B's searches.

(Unfortunately, now I've broken search entirely, so stay tuned for a new question about what the directory permissions ought to be...)